# StringUtils cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am using Java server pages and for using String Manipulations and i am Using StringUtils which i am not able compile.It says that "StringUtils cannot be resolved.". I am sorry to say that i added this to CLASSPATH, i have also put the jar file in the lib file of Apache tomcat... and in the lib file where my jsp files are located...

Actually i am using Dreamweaver trial version and programmers notepad...?

if i want to add a big import .. PLease tell me how to do so.. or do i have to compile the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is not with the classpath but the import.

Can you import the StringUtils in your jsp? Below should help

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils" %>
```

I dont see it as classpath issue, because if it was not able to locate the classes, it should have given you ClassNotFoundException. But yes, you need to have classpath set properly, which i think you have already taken care of.

Comment: Could you please mention the whole proc... please ... I have downloaded the file "commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip" from apache website and unzipped in the lib folder in tomcat... and also created a folder called lib in my project folder and still nothing.

I am still clueless... I have to do so many things... I am just using StringUtils since it has a way to chekc for null...

Comment: First thing, can you put the above statement in the jsp file? and unzip file should have commons-lang3-3.1.jar, put that in the lib.

Comment: Yes i have done that but no work.... Can you please tell me which lib file should i put.. for safety i have put in both... in JDK, in prject folder, in lib of tomcat also....

Comment: @user2524434 we're not here to hold your hand, please visit some tutorials and read a few books to gain basic knowledge like that

Comment: ok sure i will do this ,...just give me a link.. I have been developing nice time .. but never seen an error like this...